# Partition training data by class in NumPy

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

I have a 50000 x 784 data matrix (50000 samples and 784 features) and the corresponding 50000 x 1 class vector (classes are integers 0-9). I'm looking for an efficient way to group the data matrix into 10 data matrices and class vectors that each have only the data for a particular class 0-9.

I can't seem to find an elegant way to do this, aside from just looping through the data matrix and constructing the 10 other matrices that way.

Does anyone know if there is a clean way to do this with something in `scipy`, `numpy`, or `sklearn`?

Comment: Best solution depends on parameters like data size (all matrix fit into memory?), data shape ( is data numpy array, strings, ....), .... . Thanks to precise these points.

Answer (score 3):

If your `data` and `labels` matrices are in numpy format, you can do:

```
data_class_3 = data[labels == 3, :]
```

If they aren't, turn them into numpy format:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)
labels = np.array(labels)
data_class_3 = data[labels == 3, :]
```

You can loop and do this for all labels automatically if you like. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
split_classes = np.array([data[labels == i, :] for i in range(10)])
```

Comment: I don't get the `,:` in `data[labels == 3, :]`, aren't that too many indices? Isn't enough with `data[labels == 3]`?

Comment: Yes, it's enough in the 2D case. When you have more dimensions it gets complicated and I'm used to being explicit.

Comment: If you don't want to specify the range, you can use: `np.array([data[labels == i] for i in np.unique(labels)])`

Answer (score 3):

Probably the cleanest way of doing this in numpy, especially if you have many classes, is through sorting:

```
SAMPLES = 50000
FEATURES = 784
CLASSES = 10
data = np.random.rand(SAMPLES, FEATURES)
classes = np.random.randint(CLASSES, size=SAMPLES)

sorter = np.argsort(classes)
classes_sorted = classes[sorter]
splitter, = np.where(classes_sorted[:-1] != classes_sorted[1:])
data_splitted = np.split(data[sorter], splitter + 1)
```

`data_splitted` will be a list of arrays, one for each class found in `classes`. Running the above code with `SAMPLES = 10`, `FEATURES = 2` and `CLASSES = 3` I get:

```
>>> data
array([[ 0.45813694,  0.47942962],
       [ 0.96587082,  0.73260743],
       [ 0.70539842,  0.76376921],
       [ 0.01031978,  0.93660231],
       [ 0.45434223,  0.03778273],
       [ 0.01985781,  0.04272293],
       [ 0.93026735,  0.40216376],
       [ 0.39089845,  0.01891637],
       [ 0.70937483,  0.16077439],
       [ 0.45383099,  0.82074859]])

>>> classes
array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1])

>>> data_splitted 
[array([[ 0.93026735,  0.40216376],
        [ 0.70937483,  0.16077439]]),
 array([[ 0.45813694,  0.47942962],
        [ 0.96587082,  0.73260743],
        [ 0.01031978,  0.93660231],
        [ 0.45434223,  0.03778273],
        [ 0.45383099,  0.82074859]]),
 array([[ 0.70539842,  0.76376921],
        [ 0.01985781,  0.04272293],
        [ 0.39089845,  0.01891637]])]
```

If you want to make sure the sort is stable, i.e. that data points in the same class remain in the same relative order after sorting, you will need to specify `sorter = np.argsort(classes, kind='mergesort')`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the need to sort rather than index directly?

Comment: For this particular case of just 10 classes, your solution may be a better choice. But if you have many classes, you have to iterate over the whole array once for each class. Very soon the O(n log n) approach with sorting will beat the O(m n) one that comes with indexing.

Answer (score 1):

After @Jaime numpy optimal answer, I suggest you [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), specialized in data manipulations :

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame(data,index=classes).sort_index()
```

then `df.loc[i]` is your class `i`.

if you want a list, just do

```
 metadata=[df.loc[i].values for i in range(10)]
```

so `metadata[i]` is the subset you want, or make a panel with `pandas`. All that is based on numpy arrays, so efficiency is preserved.